# PHP is not passing proper data to MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, mysqli

I am unable to pass proper data to MySQL I have no idea what is wrong done by me please help me out my code is as follow:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
if($con) {
    echo "we are connected";
} else {
    die("connection failed");
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // echo "Yeah it works";
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if(!$result) {
        die("Query failed");
    }
}
```

When I run this code I'm getting `0` for `username` and `0` for `password`. whatever I type for `username` and `password` I get `0` in database.
[image]

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](//stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: First things first, `var_dump($user);` and `var_dump($password);`. Are they the correct values? Next, check the database. Is the columns `VARCHAR` or a text format (ie. Not integer). This is likely your cause.

Comment: you must pass the values into a prepared statement: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Where is your form?

Comment: check your database column structure for username. It should be varchar/text.

Comment: @EmptyBrain makes sense, probably it's all integer

Comment: You should add your HTML form and I think you're missing a `;` at the end of your query.

Comment: check the data type of the columns, it should be varchar, now its look like integer

Comment: It seems query executed but data is not inserted. Auto increament show execution of query. Your database shows that username and passwords are not of string data type, change its data type and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, which also removes [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

if(! $con )
    die('Unable to connect');

foreach(array('submit', 'username', 'password') as $arg)
    if(! isset($_POST[$arg]) )
        die('Missing argument(s)');

unset($arg);
http_response_code(200);

$username = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}')";
if(! mysqli_query($con, $query))
    http_response_code(400);
```

If this code doesn't work, make sure that *username* and *password* from your table are *varchar's* not *int's*. (Because your script inserts a *0* value)